# How to add a page on wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

i am making a custom theme using bootstrap and I am trying to make a new page, contact.php. Currently in my theme folder I have index.php, style.php and contact.php.
In my index.php I have bootstrap navmenu that looks like this

```
    <li><a href="contact.php">Contact Page</a></li>
```

But the contact page isnt loading. Do i need to add a new page from the wordpress dashboard and somwhow link it to my contact.php? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do i need to add a new page from the wordpress dashboard and somwhow link it to my contact.php?

Yes. First, create a new page from the dashboard.

Then, create a new file called `page-{slug of the page you just created}.php`.
Your page will then automatically be rendered with that template.

Now to create a link to that page, use:

```
<li>
  <a href="<?= get_permalink(get_page_by_path('map'))  ?>">Contact Page</a>
</li>
```

You can also create a template using your page id, or create a general template file then assign it to the page you created from the dashboard. [This page contains general information about creating page templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/).

Comment: The template is the better method, IMO - but yes, both methods work.

Comment: So i created a page from the dashboard and its url is `http://localhost:8888/mywebpage/contactpage/` what is the slug here? is it `contactpage`? If so, I created the page `page-contactpage`. When i try to go to that link, `http://localhost:8888/mywebpage/contactpage/`, it still renders the main `mywebpage`.

Comment: Nevermind, it works. thanks and cheers. I was doing something wrong